# recurrence bank equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

A bank pays 6% interest compounded annually on its passbook savings accounts. Suppose that you deposit $800 in one of these accounts and make no further deposits or withdrawals. Write a recurrence relation and initial conditions for b(sub)n, the balance of the account after n years.

I'm a bit nervous about this problem because it included a percentage rather than other arithmetic.

I imagine b(sub)0=800. Then b(sub)n = b(sub)n-1  * 1.06, n>=1. This seems to calculate the conditions of the question, but I'm not so sure that it actually solves the equation for compound interest. I don't know if any money can be added other than the initial 800.

edit: the next problem is for a credit card with compound interest....
the answer is bn = bn-1 + (1.5%)bn-1 - 25. => bn = (1.015)bn-1 - 25. It supposedly factors in the compound interest each month minus the monthly $25 payment.

Comment: Hint: $b_1 = b_0 \cdot 1.06$ would be the balance after $1$ year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [compound interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Discount_instruments), one gets
$$
b_n=(1+0.06)^n \times b_0
$$ or
$$
b_n=800 \times1.06^n.
$$

Comment: would bn = bn-1 * 1.06 work?

Comment: @JaredY Yes it works. The expression I gave above gives a *general* formula.